# Overpass: Busstops of Busroutes

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm pretty new to the OSM Overpass-Turbo-Coding. Started 3 hours ago, to be exactly. I'm looking for a code to extract all the buslines in a certain area including the busstops and put all that into a nice csv-file.

I experimented quite a bit and I have the feeling, that I'm very close. So I already managed to create lists with all the busroutes, a list with all the bus stops. What I did not managed to do was to export into the csv file the data of recursive operations - so id, name, ref of the route AND id, name of the subsequent bus stops of the same line (in the correct order).

Ideally, I'm thinking about a table like

```
Busline(=ref of relation)    Direction(=name of relation)    StopID (id of node)    StopName(name of node)
Line 1                       north                           123456                 MainRd
Line 1                       north                           123457                 Evergreen Terrace
Line 1                       north                           123458                 Hospital
Line 1                       north                           123459                 Dontknowwhere
......
```

.

```
 //[out:csv(::id, ::type, name, ref, role, members)];

// gather results
(
  // query part for: “Buslinie”
  relation["type"="route"]["route"="bus"]({{bbox}});
  node(r)["public_transport"="stop_position"];
);
// print results
out body;
//>;
//out;
//out skel qt;
```